# Making a table from an array of objects

Tags: php, mysql, object

I have this object:

```
stdClass Object
(
[daily_inventoryID] => 1
[inventory_timestamp] => 2012-06-08 14:35:42
[inventory_date] => 2012-06-08
[inventory] =>
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ingredientID] => 2
        [code] => Bf
        [description] => 1st Class Flour
        [volume] => 8268
        [price] => 750
        [amount_gram] => 0.02980
        [status] => Inactive
        [uom_id] => 1
        [flour] => Yes
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ingredientID] => 3
        [code] => Sf
        [description] => 3rd Class Flour
        [volume] => 18490
        [price] => 635
        [amount_gram] => 0.02540
        [status] => Inactive
        [uom_id] => 5
        [flour] => Yes
    )
...........
```

Let's say, we name the objects as $inv, i would like to display the value of $inv->inventory which is an array containing objects.

How would I do that using foreach or for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($inv->inventory as $inventory) {
  print_r($inventory);
}
```

Comment: I got 2 errors : Trying to get property of non-object and invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: $inv->inventory is correct. it displays the data when supplying it in the print_r function. but using your code, i still got those errors.

Comment: @Jetoox My code is simple enough, if `$inv->inventory` is an array, how can error happen?

Comment: I don't know man. im sure it is an array. the one i posted in my question is the exact form when i tried to print_r $inv->inventory.

Comment: @Jetoox Don't tell me that your posted is the result of `$inv->inventory`, if so, then you need `$inv->inventory->inventory`.

Comment: no. actually what is posted is the result of print_r($inv). the array of objects is the $inv->inventory.